# Query through intermediate models that returns multiple results, using Django Q object

Tags: python, django, performance

How to follow an intermediate 'through' model, in a Q object?

I'm trying to get a list of the `id`s of all `Property` objects that a `User` is a member of, in one query.

A `User` is a member of a `BusinessUnit` through `BusinessUnitMember`.

How do I make a filter with a Q object that finds all (multiple) `BusinessUnitMember`s for a particular `User`, and then finds all (multiple) `BusinessUnit`s for those `BusinessUnitMember`s?

```
class Property(BaseModel):
    """Physical Things belonging to various Business Units"""

    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    objects = PropertyQuerySet.as_manager()

    @property
    def asset(self):
        asset_maps = {
            'typea': 'type_a_asset',
            'typeb': 'type_b_asset',
        }

        if self.category not in asset_maps:
            return None
        return getattr(self, asset_maps.get(self.category), None)


class AssetBase(models.Model):
    """Abstract Base Asset model."""
    business_unit = models.ForeignKey('BusinessUnit', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class TypeAAsset(AssetBase):
    """Type A Assets"""
    property = models.OneToOneField('Property', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='type_a_asset')


class TypeBAsset(AssetBase):
    """Type B Assets"""
    property = models.OneToOneField('Property', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='type_b_asset')    

class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('core.User', null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='owned_business_units')


class BusinessUnitMember(models.Model):
    """ ``through`` model for BU and members. """
    business_unit = models.ForeignKey('BusinessUnit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey('core.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to find the `id`s of all `Property` objects that the current `User` is a member of.

I'm thinking of a filter like:

```
available_ids = Property.objects.filter(Q(type_a_asset__business_unit__in=user.businessunitmember.all().businessunit_set.all())).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

but the

```
businessunitmember_set.all().businessunit_set.all()
```

part doesn't work because `businessunitmember_set.all()` returns a queryset object which then won't have the attribute `'businessunit_set'`. Using `businessunitmember_set.get()` doesn't work either, as it would return 3 results instead of 1.

I already got it working through iterating over the individual models, but of course those create a ton of queries.

Comment: Where is the actual m2m field? Why can't you use that directly?

Comment: Is it possible to access one m2m field through the result of another m2m field, in one q object filter?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You only have one m2m field here, but you don't seem to have actually defined it as such. You need `members = models.ManyToManyField('User', through='BusinessUnitMember')` on your BusinessUnit model, then you can just do the query directly.