# Spanning a RelatedManager object in a query [Django]

Tags: python, django

1. I can span model relationships in django filters like this:

`my_asset__business_unit=user.business_unit.id`

2. If the last item returns multiple values, I can use `__in` and `all()`

`my_asset__business_unit__in=user.business_units.all()`

But how do I span where one intermediate model returns multiple values? I want to find all downstream models that match those values.

---

I tried

`my_asset__business_unit__in=user.businessunitmemberships.businessunit_set.all()`

but `businessunitmemberships` is a `'RelatedManager'` object that has no attribute `'businessunit_set'`.

I also tried 
 `my_asset__business_unit__in=user.businessunitmemberships.all().businessunit_set.all()`

but the intermediate `.all()` returns a queryset object which again won't have the attribute `businessunit_set`

I also tried
`my_asset__business_unit__in=user.businessunitmemberships.get().businessunit_set.all()`

but that doesn't work either, as the `.get()` would return 3 results instead of 1.

---

Edit: The entire models are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903253/query-through-intermediate-models-that-returns-multiple-results-using-django-q) but I think that made the question too complex.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty clear what you want to achieve, but if I understand correctly then getting all the business units related to each of the business unit membership would do:

```
my_asset__business_unit__in={
    unit
    for membership in user.businessunitmemberships.all()
    for unit in membership.businessunit_set.all()
}
```

Set comprehension is to keep the uniqueness of units.